# Has a trained martial artist ever used their hair to gain advantage or attack opponents?

Tags: technique, self-defense, kung-fu

This may sound silly, but I'm wondering if it's possible to use your hair as a weapon in a self defense situation. Perhaps as a hair-whip?

I understand that long hair is often a liability in a fight, but has a trained martial artist ever used it to their advantage?

Comment: No. Hair is too short and soft to act like a whip with any force. Precision would also be a problem. Some martial arts movies add needles and razor blades to hair, but that's just in the movies.

Comment: If you have long hair, you can use it to strangle someone, maybe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question reminded me of a Chinese Buddhist Nun, who is also a Kung Fu Master.  She pulled eight (8) cars with her hair. True story! It was reported by both *[BBCNews](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/8221933.stm) and [The Telegraph](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/newsvideo/weirdnewsvideo/6098670/Video-Buddhist-pulls-cars-with-her-hair.html).*

> "Zhang believes her hair is instilled with special powers, giving her the ability to not only slice through paper with her plait [braid], but also support great weights." *The Telegraph*

There's a [youtube video](https://youtu.be/VuKck9f521U) (in Dutch and Chinese without English translation), where you can see her pulling the cars in her last performance, before having her head shaved.

In the video, Zhang Tingting is 52 years of age. If she worked out how to pull cars with her long braid, I'm sure she figured out how to use her hair as a weapon too.

Sorry to disappoint, Grasshopper, but I couldn't find any video of Zhang Tingting practicing Kung Fu hair-slicing moves.

Comment: Who's grasshopper?

Comment: Kwai Chang Caine from the Kung Fu TV series starring David Carradine. The show was a cultural phenomenon in the 70s. Caine's teacher nicknamed him, Grasshopper.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hair_hang It' an old carnie-trick that combines specific braids with the inherent strength of regular human hair.

Comment: Yup. Nothing that can be used to actually fight. But fun to see.